# gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: linux, emacs, arch-linux

I'm trying to run `emacs 24.4-1` on up-to-date Arch Linux. My dotfiles have gone a bit awry, so I cleared out my `~/.emacs.d/` and put in it an `init.el` with this content (taken verbatim from [here](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/El-get#Installation)):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil t)
  (url-retrieve
   "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
   (lambda (s)
     (end-of-buffer)
     (eval-print-last-sexp))))
```

Upon starting `emacs --debug-init`, I get the minibuffer message:

```
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

After a while, it moves onto `Indenting region...done`(!?), which flickers occasionally. Then, in the main buffer (which previously contained:

```
Cloning into 'el-get'...
POST git-upload-pack (852 bytes)
```

) I get the extra line:

```
Congrats, el-get is installed and ready to serve!
```

However, this is not the case. Running `el-get-install` `evil` eventually yields:

```
error in process sentinel: Wrong type argument: listp, "df48f6d0aee048d76de822433b84f528"
```

after placing a few files in my `~/.emacs.d`:

```
> ls ~/.emacs.d/
el-get/  init.el
> ls ~/.emacs.d/el-get/
el-get/  undo-tree/
```

I've tried reïnstalling emacs and gnutls via `pacman -S`, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: I have seen the gnutls error message before, and I *think* it's harmless. The `evil` installation failure is probably a bug in el-get. Someone had mentioned ["complications"](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/1886#issuecomment-54936256) before, but there hasn't been an actual bug report about it.

Comment: @npostavs switching to MELPA worked. Thanks! Now, what's etiquette about adding that as an answer?

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer. If you feel like it's really not "your" answer you can make it community wiki so you get no points for it, but I don't think it matters very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a partially known issue with el-get, and it's easier to switch to another package manager (MELPA in my case).

Thanks to @npostavs for linking me to [some further discussion](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/1886#issuecomment-54936256).

Answer (score 0):

Have same error on Debian Sid. After some time Emacs crashed.

Updating **libgnutls** packages fix error:

```
$ tail /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2015-02-19  19:00:54
Upgrade: libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 (3.3.8-3, 3.3.8-5), libgnutls26:i386 (2.12.20-1, 2.12.23-18), libgnutls-openssl27:i386 (2.12.20-1, 3.3.8-5)
End-Date: 2015-02-19  19:01:00
```